# How to mix multiple Enviroment texture (not in the compositing)

Tags: texturing, node-editor

If i want to join 2 different HDR called A & B. I want to create a new Enviroment whith 180° of "A" and other part of "B". I don't want to use the compositing because i need the real effects of the 2 enviroment.

There is a genius of nodes able to do this?

Thak you!

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iamsg.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iamsg.jpg) .................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

No need to be a genius. Just mix it with a mask:

[image]

As you can see you can use a radial gradient clamped at some value with a color ramp, but image texture masks would work as well.

Comment: Grande Martin! It works